# determine if two scalars are the inner product of two vectors with the same vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Given scalars, $y_1,y_2$ and vectors **$X_1$**,**$X_2$**, can we determine whether there exists a vector **$V$** such that $y_1$ = $\left\langle X_1,V\right\rangle$ and $y_2$ = $\left\langle X_2,V\right\rangle$

thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.  I don't understand your question.  First you say $y_1=<X_1,V>$ and then you ask if it's possible to prove it.  If we already know it, what is there to prove?

Comment: sorry i didn't make my question clear i have edit it and if it's still not clear please tell me and i will do my best to improve it ,thanks

Comment: Are you asking, "Given scalars, $y_1, y_2$ and vectors $X_1, X_2$, can we determine whether there exists a vector $V$ such that $y_1=<X_1,V>, y_2=<X_2,V>$?"

Comment: yesss thank you

Comment: i will change my question to how you formed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is easy if $X_1=\mathbf{0}$ or $X_2=\mathbf{0}$, so I exclude these cases.  It is also easy if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are linearly dependent, so I assume independence.

Suppose there exist vectors $X_3, X_4$ such that $$
<X_1,X_3>=0\\
<X_2,X_3>\neq0\\
<X_2,X_4>=0\\
<X_1,X_4>\neq0$$

Then it is easy to verify that $$V=\frac{y_2}{<X_2,X_3>}X_3+\frac{y_1}{<X_1,X_4>}X_4$$
does the trick.

So, when can we find such $X_3, X_4$?  If the dimension of the space is $n>2$  then the orthogonal complement of $X_1$ has dimension $n-1$, and the orthogonal complement of $\{X_1,X_2\}$ has dimension $n-2>0$ so we can find $X_3$ orthogonal to $X_1$ but not $X_2$, and similarly we can find a suitable $X_4$.

If the dimension of the space is $2$, and if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not themselves orthogonal, then any nonzero vector orthogonal to $X_1$ serves as $X_3$ and any nonzero vector orthogonal to $X_2$ serves as $X_4$.

Now we must consider the case where $n=2$ and $<X_1,X_2>=0$, so that we can't find $X_3$ and $X_4$.  I'll leave that one up to you.  Here's a hint, though.  Under these conditions, $X_1$ and $X_2$ form a basis. You should also do the easy cases I excluded at the beginning.

**NOTE**

I'm just using "we can find" as an informal equivalent of "there exists."  I don't mean to say anything about constructibility, although of course, we can actually construct suitable vectors.